# Проблема с rigidbody2d и boxcollider2d

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы игрок не мог пройти сквозь коробки? Игрок имеет `rigidbody2d` и `boxcollider2d`, коробка имеет тоже самое. Но у игрока включена галка "`isTrigger`". Пробовал выключить это, но все равно игрок проходит сквозь коробку.
Координаты по Z одинаковые.

Comment: Ну серьезно? Таких вопросов по сайту сотня. Что так лень искать, что проще написать, да еще и не тратиться на подробное описание. Причин твоей проблемы настолько много, что из тебя придется выжимать вопросов больше, чем тут текста написано. Напишу ключевые слова, если они тебе ничего не скажут, то добро пожаловать в документацию Unity и его туторы. Слой, способы смещения игрока, матрица коллизий коллайдера vs rigidbody, матрица коллизий слоев, скорость передвижения игрока, navmesh agent, fixedUpdate.

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался! галочка "simulated" в rigidbody2d была отключена, а также нужно было добавить второй box collider2d без активного чекбокса "isTrigger"